# VIM text editor not found

Tags: vim, text-editor

I recently started to use ubuntu to program - University standards. I was checking out different text editors and tried to install VIM through Ubuntu Software Centre. Everything went fine and I got it installed, but I couldn't find the launcher (not sure if that is the right term). Any reason why this might be the case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim is a text based editor (to be used in a terminal), not a GUI program. It doesn't use menus but keyboard shortcuts. I use it a lot, but this is likely because I grow used to it long time ago, while I was working on Xenix and SCO Unix machines.

It has no launcher on the menu, open the terminal and type `vim` to start it.

Comment: What is the correct English here, "to be used on the terminal" or "to be used at the terminal"?.

Comment: I would say "in the terminal" :) But my English is quite poor, so I am not sure ....

Comment: Regarding "on" versus "at" the terminal -- in the sense you used it, I find both clear and acceptable.   "in" is perhaps better just because it is a bit more concrete (i.e., less abstract).   But "at the terminal" is fine, too -- that's a good idiomatic way to say it (in my opinion).

Comment: Jorge, LGB, jgbelacqua: Thanks for linguistic info/editing.

Answer (score 7):

vim is a command line text editor, to use it you launch a terminal and type `vim`.

If you want a graphical vim you can install [vim-gnome](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim-gnome)

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Answer (score 0):

VIM is not a GUI software, it should be run in the terminal. VIM is not so easy to operate especially for beginners, it has separated "command" and "input" mode, etc etc. The advantage: you can find at least VI (if not vim) in almost all UNIX'es or even other systems, that's why it's favorite of many people ...

Comment: Nah, it's favourite of so many because like emacs, it's super useful with amazing editing capabilities...once you get past the steep learning curve. I'll never forget watching my programmer friend editing huge swathes of code, moving immediately to specific parts of a line, etc, all with a couple keystrokes, hands never leaving the keyboard. It's not for everyone, I'll give you that.